# How to make Identityserver redirect to my web app?

Tags: docker, asp.net-identity, microservices, identityserver4, ocelot

i am trying to integrate Identity Server 4 with Ocelot and authenticate WebApp (asp.net core 3.1) then access the api if request is authenticated.

for this i have created a solution having

- Gateway- Ocelot(latest)
- IdentityService - Identity Server 4(latest)
- Sample API (asp.net core 3.1 web api)
- WebApp (asp.net core 3.1 web app)

I have added [Authorize] attribute to one of action method in homecontroller in webapp.

all above are running in docker with docker compose.

What i am able to

- hit api through Gateway
- run web APP and see UI
- WellKnown endpoint and its responding from IdentityService
- IdentityService is redirecting the browser Login page

What i am not able to

- On login page when i login with bob/bob, it remain same login page.
- I debug the  login method and found that user is successfully validated and in the end it creates a redirect URL as below

```
/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=MS.UI&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5003%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20sampleapi.read%20offline_access&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637311085925185701.MDBmN2IyNGYtYmJkNC00ODYxLWI4YTktZGZkNmUwOGNlOTI1ZTEzM2NjYjUtZjFmNC00OWFlLWJjODItNzdiZjI4MzU5OWYy&state=CfDJ8Lknm9JCWslNlbQ0xWa8fYKwi1rc-EosZtMFuCBrWuQouhK03IW5FLqKl2zjaMjUGbpl8INF4Ro2mtbe1ZODEBX8kKMi6IbHd1Dcfft9jeTCfSUBGigFm_f3vqHnGnc7TkAs_9BiFUlYNs0Cbc1xNNIXteRlLVo_aYqXzJMtnL_ZY8bk0AadRj8fx50rMDq68XVQ6tqYbx_MCAya5DGljux3UyDz8nAuS27dWoUI1hsUJ3SFC61iLqe7HHMDRyIOc3puZoDXnJOeR36xDuLiFQk8yXfmQ3L7SCNm63ZcJBGnMpZyLiUgZA-T2iBDzDriEw&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0
```

**IdentityService**
Cofig.cs

```
// Copyright (c) Brock Allen & Dominick Baier. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0. See LICENSE in the project root for license information.


using IdentityServer4;
using IdentityServer4.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace IdentityServer
{
    public static class Config
    {
        private const string SampleAPI_Secret = "tT1CCYyY7P";
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
            new IdentityResource[]
            { 
                new IdentityResources.OpenId()
            };

        public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
            new ApiScope[]
            { 
                new ApiScope("sampleapi.read","Read your data"),
                new ApiScope("sampleapi.write","Write your data"),
                new ApiScope("sampleapi.delete","Delete your data")
            };

        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources =>
             new List<ApiResource>
            {
                new ApiResource("sampleAPI", "Sample API"){
                    Scopes = { "sampleapi.read", "sampleapi.write", "sampleapi.delete" },
                }
            };
        

        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
            new Client[] 
            {
                new Client(){ 
                    ClientId = "MS.UI",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("z71C0PyDjR".Sha256()) },
                    RedirectUris ={"http://localhost:5003/signin-oidc" },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5003"},
                    FrontChannelLogoutUri = "http://localhost:5003/signout-oidc",
                    AllowedScopes = {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        "sampleapi.read",
                        "sampleapi"
                    },
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                    RequirePkce =false
                },
            
            };
    }
}
```

StartUp.cs

```
// Copyright (c) Brock Allen & Dominick Baier. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0. See LICENSE in the project root for license information.


using IdentityServer4;
using IdentityServer4.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace IdentityServer
{
    public static class Config
    {
        private const string SampleAPI_Secret = "tT1CCYyY7P";
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
            new IdentityResource[]
            { 
                new IdentityResources.OpenId()
            };

        public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
            new ApiScope[]
            { 
                new ApiScope("sampleapi.read","Read your data"),
                new ApiScope("sampleapi.write","Write your data"),
                new ApiScope("sampleapi.delete","Delete your data")
            };

        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources =>
             new List<ApiResource>
            {
                new ApiResource("sampleAPI", "Sample API"){
                    Scopes = { "sampleapi.read", "sampleapi.write", "sampleapi.delete" },
                }
            };
        

        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
            new Client[] 
            {
                new Client(){ 
                    ClientId = "MS.UI",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("z71C0PyDjR".Sha256()) },
                    RedirectUris ={"http://localhost:5003/signin-oidc" },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5003"},
                    FrontChannelLogoutUri = "http://localhost:5003/signout-oidc",
                    AllowedScopes = {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        "sampleapi.read",
                        "sampleapi"
                    },
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                    RequirePkce =false
                },
            
            };
    }
}
```

**MS.UI - Web Application Client**

StartUp.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;

using IdentityModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace MS.UI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options=> {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            }).AddCookie("Cookies")
               .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5002";
                    options.MetadataAddress = "http://identityserver/.well-known/openid-configuration";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
    {
                        // Intercept the redirection so the browser navigates to the right URL in your host
                        context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = "http://localhost:5002/connect/authorize";
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };

                    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.ClientId = "MS.UI";
                    options.ClientSecret = "z71C0PyDjR";
                    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                    //options.UsePkce = true;

                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    //options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                    options.Scope.Clear();
                    options.Scope.Add("profile");
                    options.Scope.Add("sampleapi.read");
                    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                 
                });
           
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseRouting();
            
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Modified View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - MS.UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">MS.UI</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Secure" asp-action="Secure">Secure</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2020 - MS.UI - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

In above file i just added

```
 <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Secure" asp-action="Secure">Secure</a>
                        </li>
```

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using MS.UI.Models;

namespace MS.UI.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }

        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Secure() 
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Secure page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

in above file i have added

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
   return View();
}
```

**Gateway**
StartUp.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;

namespace MS.Gateway
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var authenticationProviderKey = "TestKey";

            Action<IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions> options = o =>
            {
                o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                o.Authority = "http://identityserver";
                o.ApiName = "sampleAPI";
                o.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Both;
                o.ApiSecret = "secret";
            };

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(authenticationProviderKey, options);
            services.AddOcelot();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
            app.UseOcelot().Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

ocelot.json

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "MS.api",
          "Port": 80
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
        "GET",
        "POST",
        "PUT",
        "DELETE"
      ],
      "RouteIsCaseSensitive": false,
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "TestKey",
        "AllowedScopes": [ "sampleAPI" ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:5001"
  }
}
```

Docker Compose

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  ms.api:
    image: msapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MS.API/Dockerfile
  
  ms.gateway:
    image: ms.gateway
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: MS.Gateway/Dockerfile

  identityserver:
    image: identityserver
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: IdentityServer/Dockerfile
  
  ms.ui:
    image: ms.ui
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: MS.UI/Dockerfile
```

Docker Compose Override

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  ms.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
   
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - C:/Users/dheer/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
    networks: 
      - msnetwork

  ms.gateway:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
    ports:
      - "5001:80"
    networks: 
      - msnetwork

  identityserver:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
    ports:
      - "5002:80"
    networks: 
      - msnetwork

  ms.ui:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
    ports:
      - "5003:80"
    networks: 
      - msnetwork

networks: 
  msnetwork:

volumes: 
  gateway_voludme:
```

Please help me .
this complete source code is also available @ https://github.com/Dheerajmentor/Microservice.git
Branch  -  Add-IDS4

Comment: Questions in StackOverflow are to be answered here, and the needed code etc needs to be included in the question. This is not a place for asking work requests on your repo.

Comment: My intention is not to ask anyone to work on my repo, I thought there is so much code so it will easy for them to look on github.. Sorry about that

Comment: whats your identityserver settings? @DheerajKumar and as James suggested try to post your code snippets here and add reference to gh repo - this would help you to get faster response

Comment: Sure i will do that

Comment: @nahidf  , i have update the question as per suggestions

Comment: Can I ask why do you use hybrid flow? any specific reason? forexample do you have a usecase to use id token? I believe what you need is code flow based on ur code - once you decided about the flow then fixing the issue would be much easier

Comment: I have use case like , Web Application and android application , do you think i should mode to "Code" flow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the Code_challenge required error, then that's because the client didn't sent the following two PKCE headers:

```
&code_challenge=XXXXXXXXX...
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

Do verify this in Fiddler.

Also, do uncomment this line is a good start:

```
//options.UsePkce = true;
```

Also looking at the IdentityServer log is a good place to diagnose this further.

Also, PKCE is only available for the Authorization code flow. You are using

```
AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
```

When you should use this instead:

```
AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
```

If you still want to use the current Hybrid flow, you need to disable PKCE using
the following in the client definition:

```
RequirePkce = false
```

Comment: Logs shows below 
[18:13:07 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
Checking for PKCE parameters

[18:13:07 Error] IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
code_challenge is missing

[18:13:07 Error] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
Request validation failed

Comment: i have commented the line
and Yes those 2 headers are not being sent
Please guide what should i do ?

Comment: I improved the answer

Comment: If I need to disable Pkce then should I be setting it true at first place?

Comment: No, you set it to false in the client definition to disable PKCE for that specific client.

Comment: Sure I will try in morning

Comment: i tried and now its redirecting it to Login. But Now problem is that even after login (using bob/bob test users) its still remain on Login page and does not redirect to MS.UI

Comment: i am using Hybrid because of kind of flow it provides

Comment: You should try to only use the authorization code flow or client credentials flow, because of the various security issues with the other flows. PKCE should be used for modern applications. But your client then needs to provide the PKCE headers.